# Issues mapping a document with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that I was hoping to store in ElasticSearch and be able to run queries against, but I think the document structure is possibly badly formed and as such I wont be able to do effective queries.

The document is trying to be generic and as such, has a set of repeating structures.

For example:

```
  description : [
    { type : "port", value : 1234 }.
    { type : "ipaddress", value : "192.168.0.1" },
    { type : "path", value : "/app/index.jsp app/hello.jsp" },
    { type : "upsince", value : "2014-01-01 12:00:00" },
    { type : "location", value : "-40, 70" }
  ]
```

Note: Ive simplified the example, as in the real document the repeating structure has about 7 fields, of which 3 fields will explicitly identify the "type".

From the above example I can't see how I can write a mapping, as the "value" could either be an:

- Integer
- IP Address
- A field that needs to be tokenized by only whitespace
- A datetime
- A GEO Point

The only solution I can see is that the document needs to be converted into another format that would more easily map with ElasticSearch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is somewhat described here: http://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/#keyvalue-woes

You can't have different kinds of values in the same field. What you can do is to have different fields like `location_value`, `timestamp_value`, and so on.

Here's a runnable example: https://www.found.no/play/gist/ad90fb9e5210d4aba0ee

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "integer_value": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "timestamp_value": {
                            "type": "date"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"description":[{"type":"port","integer_value":1234},{"type":"upsince","timestamp_value":"2014-01-01T12:00:00"}]}
'
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner. That linkyou provided was excellent. I rearranged my key value data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You're doing to save yourself a lot of headaches if you convert them documents like this first

```
{
  "port": 1234,
  "ipaddress" : "192.168.0.1" ,
  "path" : "/app/index.jsp app/hello.jsp",
  "upsince" : "2014-01-01 12:00:00",
  "location" : "-40, 70" 
}
```

Elasticsearch is designed to be flexible when it comes to fields and values, so it can already deal with pretty much any key/value combination you throw at it.

Optionally you can include the original document in a field that's explicitly stored but not indexed in case you need the orginal document returned in your queries.